# Computing the determinant of an $n \times n$ matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

I am having a problem with computing the determinant of the following $n \times n$ matrix. Can you help me?

> $$A = \begin{bmatrix}1 & 1 & \cdots & 1 & 0 & 1 \\ 1 & \kern3mu\raise1mu{.}\kern3mu\raise6mu{.}\kern3mu\raise12mu{.} & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 \\ \vdots & \kern3mu\raise1mu{.}\kern3mu\raise6mu{.}\kern3mu\raise12mu{.} & \kern3mu\raise1mu{.}\kern3mu\raise6mu{.}\kern3mu\raise12mu{.} & \kern3mu\raise1mu{.}\kern3mu\raise6mu{.}\kern3mu\raise12mu{.} & \kern3mu\raise1mu{.}\kern3mu\raise6mu{.}\kern3mu\raise12mu{.} & \vdots \\ 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & \kern3mu\raise1mu{.}\kern3mu\raise6mu{.}\kern3mu\raise12mu{.} & 1 \\ 0 & 1 & 1 & \kern3mu\raise1mu{.}\kern3mu\raise6mu{.}\kern3mu\raise12mu{.} & 1 & 1 \\ 1 & 1 & \cdots & 1 & 1 & 1\end{bmatrix}$$

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Answer (score 2):

Since adding multiples of any row of a matrix to another row leaves the determinant unchanged, we can subtract the last row of the matrix from all of the other row to obtain the matrix
$$
\det A = \begin{vmatrix}
1 & 1 & \cdots & 1 & 0 & 1 \\
1 & \ddots & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 \\
\vdots & \ddots & \ddots & \ddots & \ddots & \vdots \\
1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & \ddots & 1 \\
0 & 1 & 1 & \ddots & 1 & 1 \\
1 & 1 & \cdots & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
\end{vmatrix}=\begin{vmatrix}
0 & 0 & \cdots & 0 & -1 & 0 \\
0 & \ddots & 0 & -1 & 0 & 0 \\
\vdots & \ddots & \ddots & \ddots & \ddots & \vdots \\
0 & -1 & 0 & 0 & \ddots & 0 \\
-1 & 0 & 0 & \ddots & 0 & 0 \\
1 & 1 & \cdots & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
\end{vmatrix}
$$

Now the top $n-1$ row contain a $-1$ in the $(n-1)$th position, and all zeros elsewhere. We can now subtract each of these rows in turn from the last row to transform it into a row of zeros with a $1$ in the $n$th position. Again, this does not change the value of the determinant:

$$
\det A = \begin{vmatrix}
0 & 0 & \cdots & 0 & -1 & 0 \\
0 & \ddots & 0 & -1 & 0 & 0 \\
\vdots & \ddots & \ddots & \ddots & \ddots & \vdots \\
0 & -1 & 0 & 0 & \ddots & 0 \\
-1 & 0 & 0 & \ddots & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & \cdots & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
\end{vmatrix}
$$

We can then multiply each of the upper rows by $-1$ to change those $-1$s to $1$s. Multiplying any given row of a matrix by a scalar multiplies the determinant of the matrix by the same factor, so this will update the determinant by $(-1)^{n-1}$:

$$
\det A = (-1)^{n-1} \begin{vmatrix}
0 & 0 & \cdots & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & \ddots & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
\vdots & \ddots & \ddots & \ddots & \ddots & \vdots \\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & \ddots & 0 \\
1 & 0 & 0 & \ddots & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & \cdots & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
\end{vmatrix}
$$

Swap the bottom row with the $(n-1)$th row, then swap the $(n-1)$th with the $(n-2)$th, and so on and so forth until the bottom row is at the top of the matrix. This operation involves $n-1$ row exchanges, and each row exchange scale the determinant by a factor of $-1$, so the result is
$$
\det A = (-1)^{n-1} (-1)^{n-1}\begin{vmatrix}
0 & 0 & \cdots & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & \cdots & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & \ddots & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
\vdots & \ddots & \ddots & \ddots & \ddots & \vdots \\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & \ddots & 0 \\
1 & 0 & 0 & \ddots & 0 & 0 \\
\end{vmatrix} = \begin{vmatrix}
0 & 0 & \cdots & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & \cdots & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & \ddots & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
\vdots & \ddots & \ddots & \ddots & \ddots & \vdots \\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & \ddots & 0 \\
1 & 0 & 0 & \ddots & 0 & 0 \\
\end{vmatrix}
$$
Now we go in for the kill. Let's convert this matrix into the $n \times n$ identity matrix. When $n$ is even, this will require swapping the top $n/2$ rows with the bottom $n/2$ rows, which will change the determinant by a factor of $(-1)^{n/2}$. When $n$ is odd, we can see that $(\frac{n+1}{2})$th row is already where it need to be, so we need only perform $\frac{n-1}{2}$ row exchanges. Again, this changes the determinant by a factor of $(-1)^{\frac{n-1}{2}}$.
Hence,
$$
\det A = \begin{cases} (-1)^\frac{n}{2}, & \text{ whenever $n$ is even} \\
(-1)^{\frac{n-1}{2}}, & \text { whenever $n$ is odd}
\end{cases}.
$$
which can be given even more simply as
$$
\det A = (-1)^{\left\lfloor \frac{n}{2} \right\rfloor}
$$
where $\lfloor \cdot \rfloor$ is the [greatest integer function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floor_and_ceiling_functions).